# Stack doesn't work inside Column - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, stack, flutter-layout

Hope u all doing well. I have a problem with Stack and Column. When I want to use Stack inside Column's children, it doesn't work, anymore. here are 2 photos regarding my problem. 
Not working: 
[image]

Working: 
[image]

Comment: what is the problem what u wanna do ? if you send me photos and write what you want i can tell you

Comment: Never add prints of the code. You should always write the code in the question. It is important for legibility, searchability and accessibility.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since column and stack will take up the screen size. To be able to use both together, you need to give the contents a certain height or need to be wrapped with expanded

```
Column(
  children: [
    Container(),
    Container(
      height: 100,
      child: Stack(),
    ), //container or expanded
  ],
 )
```